# matplotlib plot matrix keeping the original coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib, geospatial

I have two vectors `x` and `y` and a matrix such that `z[i,j] = f(x[i], y[j])`

I would like to plot `z` keeping on the axis the coordinates in `x` and `y`.  In other words the point `z[i, j]` should stay in position `x[i], y[j]` in the plot.

I need to keep this relationship because I need to overlap different plots.

`plt.imshow(z)` does not work as `z[i,j]` is in position `(i, j)` and not `(x[i], x[j])`

How can I solve?

EDIT:
I need a 2 dimensional representation

Answer (score 2):

you possibly could use a scatter plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
N = 40
X = np.random.rand(N)
Y = np.random.rand(N)
def f(x,y): #function f
    return x+y
Z = np.zeros([N,N])
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        Z[i,j] = f(X[i],Y[j])
        plt.scatter(X[i],Y[j],c=Z[i,j],s=40,vmin=0.0,vmax=2.0,cmap='viridis',marker='s')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38953668/plotting-2-variables-with-a-heat-map/39919592#comment67487195_39919592 for a solution to avoid the scatterplot in a loop by using meshgrid.